# My default search is not working

Tags: search

I am using a fucntion to search my `post_meta` which i store with every post, But the problem is that when i search `title`, `tags`, content then the search not work. I think my new `function` just override the default search of wordpress. Here is my code

```
function custom_search_query( $query ) {
    $custom_fields = array(
        // put all the meta fields you want to search for here
        "post_state",
        "post_region",
        "post_country"
        );
    $searchterm = $query->query_vars['s'];
    // we have to remove the "s" parameter from the query, because it will prevent the posts from being found
    $query->query_vars['s'] = "";
    if ($searchterm != "") {
        $meta_query = array('relation' => 'OR');
        foreach($custom_fields as $cf) {
            array_push($meta_query, array(
                'key' => $cf,
                'value' => $searchterm,
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
                ));
        }
        $query->set("meta_query", $meta_query);
    }
}
add_filter( "pre_get_posts", "custom_search_query");
```

So where is i am wrong. Any idea how can i search every thing. My custom `post_meta`,`title`,`tags`,`categories`,`content`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to modify Wordpress search SQL query instead of adding extra meta query.

try this:

```
function search_distinct($distinct) {
    $distinct = 'DISTINCT';
    return $distinct;
}

function join_table($join){
    global $wpdb;
    $join .= "LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta ON ($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id) ";
    return $join;
}

function search_into_post_meta( $search, $wp_query )
{
    if ( is_search() ) {
        global $wpdb;
        if ( empty( $search ) )
            return $search;
        $q = $wp_query->query_vars;
        $n = ! empty( $q['exact'] ) ? '' : '%';
        $search =
        $searchand = '';
         foreach ( (array) $q['search_terms'] as $term ) {
            $term = esc_sql( like_escape( $term ) );
            $search .= "{$searchand} ( ($wpdb->posts.post_title LIKE '{$n}{$term}{$n}') OR ($wpdb->posts.post_content LIKE '{$n}{$term}{$n}') OR ($wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = 'post_state' AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value LIKE '{$n}{$term}{$n}') OR ($wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = 'post_region' AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value LIKE '{$n}{$term}{$n}') OR ($wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = 'post_country' AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value LIKE '{$n}{$term}{$n}'))";
            $searchand = ' AND ';
        }
        if ( ! empty( $search ) ) {
            $search = " AND ({$search}) ";
            if ( ! is_user_logged_in() )
                $search .= " AND ($wpdb->posts.post_password = '') ";
        }
        add_filter('posts_distinct_request', 'search_distinct');
        add_filter('posts_join_request','join_table');
        return $search;
    }
return $search;
}

add_filter( 'posts_search', 'search_into_post_meta', 500, 2 );
```

Comment: +1 But: You don't need to `esc_sql()` for `like_escape()`. Maybe you could explain the `exact` query variable and its usage a bit.

Comment: My tags and categories still not working in search, have you any idea @nick